# Call function with current reference in jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in jquery template and I want to call a javascript function from template. e.g.

My div in jquery template is as follows:

```
<div class="div1" ${makeContainer(this)}>
</div>
```

'makeContainer' is a function in javascript. I am unable to pass the reference of current element i.e. 'div1' in 'this' parameter.

Please help

Comment: What template system are you using?

Comment: @GuidoKitzing : its jquery template

Answer (score 0):

You can select all div with class `div1` and call function for each element.

```
$('.div1').each(function(){
    makeContainer($(this));
});
```

So in html you can just use

```
<div class="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can't i call the function from template

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement. Do you mean to pass the reference of div?
Anyway I have created a demo which may be useful to you

HTML

```
<div id = "div_1" onclick="myDemoFunc(this)">Hello
</div>
```

JS

```
function myDemoFunc(elem){
    var getElem = elem;
    var id= getElem.id;
    alert(id);
    }
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/xf70fo95/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply...but my html is written inside the template and I want to call the function while the template is being rendered by the browser and not on some event e.g. "onclick" like you diid.

Comment: onload event cannot be fired on div. So I need to look at your code which is loading the template

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
```

**And JS Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.div1').each(function(){
        makeContainer($(this));
      });

  });

  function makeContainer(value)
  {
      console.log(value);
  }
</script>
```